# Forbid file creation in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

- Is it possible to forbid file creation in a Docker image?
- That is, once the image is built with a `Dockerfile`, it is not allowed to create further files.
- The exact scenario (probably irrelevant) is that I have a crashing program that creates all kinds of temporary files in `/tmp/...`, and I want to watch the first time it complains about that.

Comment: Short answer: no. You will always be able to run the container as root user and do whatever you whish in there. Meanwhile you could run your program as a specific user and have it write in a directory where is does not have permission. But as you said, that looks a bit awkward debugging scenario...

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks, if I control the command line that launches the docker, does your answer change? I mean maybe something like: `docker exec -it --readonly my_docker`

Comment: Your initial question was basically: "Is it possible to create an image in such a way that it is impossible to create any file in any container that runs out of it?". My answer did not change: NO. You can run your container with the `-read-only` flag which will make its root filesystem read-only. Meanwhile note that this is a `docker run` option and not a `docker exec` one. This might fulfill your awkward requirement if your application writes to the root filesystem. `/tmp` is usually on the root filesystem but could be somewhere else depending on your exact image.

Comment: Oh I see thanks - if you can write your notes as an answer I will gladly accept. Otherwise I can summarize your comments to answer myself - let me know what works out best for you.

Comment: You can self-answer if you really feel it's worth it.